# What Meaning Of This Function

Tags: octave

```
function [TC]=Translate(T0,Base)
end
```

I know that Translate is a function and T0 and Base his parameter but **what is [TC]**?

Comment: Thermodynamic Calculation ? You tell us whats TC, youre the one looking at code

Comment: The output of the function `Translate`, although given that it is never defined within the function you've shown it's actually nothing and this would throw an error...

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Defining-Functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octave (and matlab) have a rather unique way of returning variables from functions. Instead of defining explicitly what to return from the function using a `return` keyword, they define from the outset which variables will be returned when the function exits, and octave simply looks for those variables by name at the time the function exits, and returns their values, whatever they may be by that point.

Your function may return nothing:

```
function returnsNothing();
  disp('hello, I return nothing');
end
```

or it may return one output:

```
function Out = returnsOne(x)
  Out = x+5
  disp('This function will return the value of Out');
end
```

or it may return more than one outputs:

```
function [Out1, Out2] = returnsTwo(x)
  Out1 = x+5; 
  Out2 = x+10;
end
```

You would call the last function from the octave terminal (or script) like this:

```
[a,b] = returnsTwo(5);  % this will make a = 10 and b = 15
```